# Magento Advanced Dataflow profile not working

Tags: database, magento, import, dataflow

I could use some help from a magento expert.

I've installed a fresh magento 1.7 installation in a subfolder of my old site, when the site is filled with all the products I'll copy it to the main folder.

Now I want to import products using the import/export advanced data profile. When I try to run the profile the pop-up window opens, but it doesn't get further than, "Starting profile execution, please wait...   And nothing happens , it just stays like that.

This wasn't a problem with my previous magento installation. The profile would just run and import all the products.

I have no idea how to solve this and would be very thankful if anyone could help me out with this.

Answer (score 0):

This Dataflow screen is made in Javascript and Ajax requests. If nothing happens, you can have two types of errors :

- Javascript error : turn on the Debug panel of your browser (Firebug for example) and go to the "Console" tab and check if an JS error is showed. If this is the case, put it here.
- PHP error : on the Debug panel of your browser, go to the "Network" tab and check the response result of the Ajax request that Dataflow sends. You should see a PHP error. If not, check your magento logs.

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help out. I've done what you said, checked with firebug and there's indeed a javascript error shown.

Comment: TypeError: $(...) is null
 

$("updatedRows_img").src = config.styles.message.icon;

Comment: From there i'm afraid you'll have to search yourself for this missing "updatedRows_img" (search that on all your sources).

Comment: Ok I'll do that. Thank you very much for the advice.

Answer (score 0):

My server didn't accept LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE. I have modified the code, now it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to export the few products, if it works you just need to change the settings below, so you will be able to export many.

You can go increasing the limit in your **php.ini** according to the settings of your server.

- max_input_time
- memory_limit
- post_max_size
- allow_url_fopen
- max_input_vars